# Get all values from columns with duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I have a SQL query on a reservations table (attributes: name, day, start, finish) which finds duplicate values for the days attribute:

```
SELECT day, COUNT(day) as NumberOfTimes 
FROM reservation group by day HAVING (COUNT(day)>1) 
ORDER BY NumberOfTimes
```

But it only returns the day and the Number of Times that day is listed in the reservations table. I am trying to get the return to list every name listed for that day, but i'm having trouble with the grouping of the query. How should I approach this is i want the return to look like:

```
BOB   MONDAY  3
JOHN  MONDAY  3
STEVE MONDAY  3
ALICE WEDNESDAY 2
MARTIN WEDNESDAY 2
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is it correct that, in your desired output, Bob has made 3 reservations on Monday ?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you add a column for name

```
SELECT
  name,
  day,
  COUNT(day) as NumberOfTimes
FROM reservation
group by name , day
HAVING (COUNT(day) > 1)
ORDER BY NumberOfTimes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery which will allow you to add more columns that are not including in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select r1.name,
    r2.day,
    r2.NumberOfTimes
from reservation r1
inner join
(
    SELECT day, COUNT(day) as NumberOfTimes 
    FROM reservation 
    group by day 
    HAVING (COUNT(day)>1) 
) r2
    on r1.day = r2.day
order by NumberOfTimes
```

If you only want the name as the additional column, then you can use:

```
SELECT name, day, COUNT(day) as NumberOfTimes 
FROM reservation 
group by day, name
HAVING (COUNT(day)>1) 
order by NumberOfTimes
```

Comment: @raheelshan I am showing an alternate way.  If for example, they wanted to add more columns to the query then just grouping by name would not return the correct values to the other columns. You would have to use a  subquery